# Tips on switching to Linux?

Tags: linux, distributions, gui, desktop-environment

I plan to switch to Linux as my sole OS in a few weeks/months, and I'm not sure what I'd like to do.

I've used CentOS Server, but only in CLI mode, and Ubuntu Desktop.

I liked Ubuntu, but Unity was just horrible.

Can anyone recommend a good distro and a good DE?
And tips on how to install the DE? I'm not good with installing GUIs, aha.

Comment: I suggest experimentation. Options include Fedora, Debian, Gentoo. What you want depends on some extent on what you want to do with it.

Comment: I'd use it for a development environment or maybe a few Samba shares. Not sure.

Comment: Yes, I'd experiment. Most of the distributions people mention are similar in what software they contain, to a first approximation. Of course there are differences, but they should not be of immediate concern if you are just starting.I personally use Debian and would recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a Fedora user and hence I am going to recommend it. The [default](http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora) Fedora desktop ISO is a Live image with GNOME 3 as the DE.

But you have a number of other [choices](http://spins.fedoraproject.org/).

Comment: KDE is also a good desktop on Fedora if GNOME doesn't appeal to you.